# Magnetic horn function

Tags: electromagnetism, particle-physics, particle-detectors

I wonder how a [magnetic horn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_horn) works. I can imagine that a magnetic field will distract particles due to their charge but what I don't understand is, how to isolate antiprotons? 
The charge is probably negative but then still all negatively charged particles will remain?

Is it possible to tune a magnetic horn such that it connects to masses? Can the magnetic force be applied to charge and also mass? If so, then probably through the [lorentz force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_force). Is this how it works?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confusing antiprotons with antineutrinos. We don't have to worry about isolating antineutrinos, because they isolate themselves. They go streaking off at near the speed of light and rarely interact with anything. Antiprotons are very rare on Earth, as they soon annihilate on contact with matter. As you correctly say, they are negatively charged, which means that they repel all other negatively charged particles. Isolating them is the only way to prevent them from annihilating. That would have to be done by magnetically levitating them in a vacuum, which would be very difficult, though possible in theory.

Comment: I know that the wikipedia article relates to neutrinos, but magnetic horns are also used to isolate antiprotons as there is a particle accelerator build up to use them. So my question remains?